# Is there a way to disinclude an index value so it can search for the next index occurance in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this function in Excel but I want to fill a whole column automatically whenever the source data is changed.

```
 =INDEX('Building Reference'!$A$3:$B$35,MATCH("FLUID",'Building Reference'!$B3:$B$35,0),1)
```

---

```
DD142   TOTE
DD143   TOTE
DD144   CART
DD145   CART
DD146   CART
DD147   CART
DD148   CART
DD149   VRETS
DD150   CART
DD151   CART
DD152   FLUID
DD153   CART
DD154   CART
DD155   CART
DD156   CART
DD157   FLUID
DD158   FLUID
DD160   FLUID
DD161   FLUID
DD162   FLUID
DD163   CART
DD164   FLUID
DD165   FLUID
DD166   FLUID
DD167   AIR
DD168   AIR
DD169   AIR
DD170   AIR
DD171   AIR
DD172   TRANS
DD173   TRANS
DD174   TRANS
DD175   TRANS
```

Column  a are the DD's and column b are the types of doors they are.

I want to be able to automatically pull the doors that say fluid into another column.

Comment: `FILTER()` does what you describe in your last sentence.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for a spill formula. There are a few options.

Using a fixed input range and a dynamic output range:

```
=FILTER(A3:A35,B3:B35="FLUID","- NONE -")
```

Or having your input range include all possible rows:

```
=FILTER(A3:A1048576,B3:B1048576="FLUID","- NONE -")
    - or -
=FILTER(FILTER(A:A, ROW(A:A)>=3),FILTER(B:B, ROW(B:B)>=3)="FLUID","- NONE -")
    - or -
=FILTER(A:A,B:B="FLUID","- NONE -")
```